# MASM - Read multiple integer data using invoke crt_scanf

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am trying to create an array to store 10 dword integers. To allow users to type in their own integers, I use jumps to implement it.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc
include user32.inc
include msvcrt.inc
includelib msvcrt.lib

.data
InputMsg db "Input 10 integers: (Separated by Space)", 10, 0
IntFormat db "%d", 0

.data?
IntData dword 10 dup(?)

.code
start:
    invoke crt_printf, addr InputMsg
    mov dh, 0
    lea eax, IntData
    ScanLoop:
        invoke crt_scanf, addr IntFormat, dword ptr [eax]
        inc eax
        inc dh
    cmp dh, 10
    js  ScanLoop

    invoke ExitProcess, NULL
end start
```

But here goes the problem. I tried to run the program, and it succeeded to compile. However the program goes wrong after one integer is input.
Why would it happen? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because scanf clobbers EAX with a return value? As ell each `dword` is 4 bytes long. Incrementing EAX to go to the next DWORD would have been going to the next byte.

Comment: Also seems you want to pass the address for scanf to write to not the value. How about `invoke crt_scanf, addr IntFormat, eax`

Comment: As well your loop will likely fail to exit. besides _EAX_ being clobbered by the call to `scanf` so are _ECX_ and _EDX_  (per the CDECL calling convention). You can't rely on any of those 3 to have the values they had before the call. You could use registers other than _EAX_ and _EDX_ for keeping track of the array pointer and the loop counter (like _EBX_, _ESI_, _EDI_ which won't be clobbered)

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Now I use `invoke crt_scanf, addr IntFormat, eax` and `add eax, 4`, but error still occurs when TWO integers are input.

Comment: You didn't read all I said. The last parameter being wrong was only part of the problem. The other issue is that _EAX_ gets destroyed by scanf so the address in _EAX_ before the scanf call will be gone after. The value in _EDX_ as well. I suggested using registers other than _EAX_. _ECX_, and _EDX_ since all threee of those can possible be clobbered per the CDECL calling convention. You can use _EBX_, _ESI_ and _EDI_ which are preserved across CDECL function calls.

Comment: Oh I see! Problem solved! Thank you very much :)